# event sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after is not being dispatch over REST API

Tags: magento2, event-observer, api, rest-api

May I know how can I dispatch event `sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after` when I create invoice via `REST api`?

I noticed there are quite a number of extensions is observing this particular event but this event is not being dispatched when the invoice is created over `REST api`.

Is this function depreciated? I understand that this event works well in the web but there is dispatching in `REST api`.

Comment: What is the location of the events.xml?

Comment: your issue resolved ia m facing same issue but in  my case its working for old user not working with guest

Answer (score 0):

you should use event "sales_order_invoice_save_after" instead